# Python Index Error Using CSV File to Create Venn Diagram

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a Venn Diagram using the information on a CSV file I created. However, I am getting an index error on line 13 of my code with it saying the list index is out of range. I was hoping to see if anybody here might have any ideas on why that is. This is the code I am using to try and create the Venn diagram:

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from sympy import FiniteSet

def get_Sports(file_name):
    football=[]
    others=[]
    with open(file_name) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            if row[1] == 1:
                football.append(row[0])
            if row[2] == 1:
                others.append(row[0])
    return football, others

def plot_venn(f, o):
    venn2(subsets=(f, o))
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = input('Input the file path with the list of student ids, whether they play football, and whether they play other sports: ')
    football, others = get_Sports(file)
    football = FiniteSet(*football)
    others = FiniteSet(*others)
    plot_venn(football, others)
```

Here is the CSV File that I am using:

```
ID, Football, Other Sports
1, 1, 0
2, 0, 1
3, 0, 0
4, 1, 1
5, 1, 0
6, 0, 0
7, 0, 0
8, 1, 1
9, 1, 1
10, 1, 0
```

Comment: The values you get back from `csv.reader` in `row` are strings. Your code is comparing them to integers. So the `if` tests both fail and the `append()` calls never happen.

Comment: please copy the entire error message into your question as code

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your logic as when you read csv, it's storing the value as a string. So `row[1] == 1` will be `False` because `row[1]` is `'1'`.

For your code to work, your function would need to be:

```
def get_Sports(file_name):
    football=[]
    others=[]
    with open(file_name) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            if row[1].strip() == '1':
                football.append(row[0])
            if row[2].strip() == '1':
                others.append(row[0])
    return football, others
```

Personally I like `pandas` rather the `csv`. So I did the same as you, just using pandas and then use the logic to ultimately get what you are after. This would be a better/faster method if your csv file is huge:

```
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sympy import FiniteSet

def get_Sports(file_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    football = list(df[df.iloc[:,1] == 1].iloc[:,0])
    others = list(df[df.iloc[:,-1] == 1].iloc[:,0])
    
    return football, others

def plot_venn(f, o):
    venn2(subsets=(f, o), set_labels = ('Football', 'Other Sports'))
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = input('Input the file path with the list of student ids, whether they play football, and whether they play other sports: ')
    football, others = get_Sports(file)
    football = FiniteSet(*football)
    others = FiniteSet(*others)
    plot_venn(football, others)
```

**Output:**

[image]